# How would I update a field to set a default value?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

After updating an existing django field to have a default value if I save the field with a null value I get the error: *IntegrityError: null value in column*

rather than the field being set to the default, does anyone know why this may be? If I include null=True it just sets it to null.

Answer (score 1):

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
      your_given_field = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='default_value')

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.your_given_field:
        self.your_given_field = 'default_value'
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: looking for a solution that doesnt include more code, looking to fix the database setup really

Answer (score 0):

I think by explicitly trying to save the field as null you are overriding the default value. Try and update the object only if the variable exists.

```py
my_variable = None

if my_variable:
    my_object.my_field = my_variable
```

if you post more of your code i could help more

Comment: if you try and save a field as anything other than null it wont use the default value? the code is irrelevant as I'm just saving a record to a model, code would be Model.objects.create()

Comment: It is true that the default will not be used if you save a column other than null. It is also true that the *default will not be used if you save a column is null*. **NULL is a value**. The default is only used when the column is not mentioned by the insert statement or the key word DEFAULT (insert or update) is supplied for the value. See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Jkowe4Hx).